# Convert date format into another format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a hash whose keys are strings expressing dates in format `"%W %Y"`:

```
{"11 2016"=>255000.0, "12 2016"=>255000.0, "13 2016"=>255000.0, "14 2016"=>255000.0, "15 2016"=>255000.0, "16 2016"=>255000.0, "17 2016"=>255000.0, "18 2016"=>255000.0, "19 2016"=>255000.0, "20 2016"=>255000.0}
```

I want to convert the keys into Month/Year format to get something like this:

```
{"March 2016"=>255000.0, "March 2016"=>255000.0, "April 2016"=>255000.0, "April 2016"=>255000.0, "April 2016"=>255000.0, "May 2016"=>255000.0, "May 2016"=>255000.0, "May 2016"=>255000.0, "June 2016"=>255000.0, "June 2016"=>255000.0}
```

I tried this:

UPDATE

```
def conv_to_month(hash)
    dates_array = []
    values = []
    hash.each do |k, v|
        date = Date.strptime(k, '%W %Y')
        newdate = date.strftime('%B %Y')
        puts newdate
        dates_array << newdate
        values << v
    end
    result = Hash[dates_array.zip(values)]
end
```

but I get an invalid date error, and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the date strings via [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
date = Date.strptime('11 2016', '%W %Y')
#=> #<Date: 2016-03-14>
```

and re-format the resulting date via [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime):

```
date.strftime('%B %Y')
#=> "March 2016"
```

**But** keep in mind that a hash can only contain each key once, so you can't have two keys with `"March 2016"` (unless you enable [`compare_by_identity`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-compare_by_identity)). You might want to use an array instead or – alternatively – use the given hash and format the string using a helper when printing the string (formatting is usually view-related).

Comment: I tried this way but when i do date = Date.strptime(k, '%W %Y') i get invalid date error

Comment: @AntoineWako _"i get invalid date error"_ – for what `k`?

Comment: the value after 2016 @Stefan

Comment: Sorry, i mean it works until the key = '01 2017', it fail when its the next year

Comment: @AntoineWako a) `'01 2017'` is not in your example data and b) `Date.strptime('01 2017', '%W %Y')` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be something like this:

```
data = {"11 2016"=>255000.0, "12 2016"=>255000.0, "13 2016"=>255000.0, "14 2016"=>255000.0, "15 2016"=>255000.0, "16 2016"=>255000.0, "17 2016"=>255000.0, "18 2016"=>255000.0, "19 2016"=>255000.0, "20 2016"=>255000.0}

data.map {|k, v| month, year = k.split(' '); [[ Date::MONTHNAMES[month.to_i], year].join(' '), v]}.to_h
```

But in this case the first part of the date must correspond to month number correctly. Like 1 would be January and 12 would be December.

Comment: Thanks for your help but yes the first part is the number of the week in the year not the months